# Callbacks from C native to Xamarin native

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My requirement is to implement the async call from native c library to xamarin native application to get all the data coming from server.

```
/**
 * @brief OOB Data receive callback (__NULLABLE)
 *
 * When receiving data from the sender this function is called.
 * You get a pointer to the data, the length and the NetworkConnection object containing your
 * object if you did put a object there.
 *
 * @param function getting data from the sender.
 */

std::function<void(const uint8_t *pBuf, size_t lSize, std::shared_ptr<NetworkConnection> &rConnection, rist_peer *pPeer)>
        networkOOBDataCallback = nullptr;
```

I am getting all data in this callback coming from sender server.

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: You can try to compile the `C` source code into platform-specific native libraries , so that it can be called by the C# wrapper , check the details here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/ .

Comment: Thank you for your response. @ColeX-MSFT
I have already tried all ways the but it's not working.
I want continuous callback from c wrapper to c# android project.

Comment: Which part does not work ? Can you provide more details?